# Error while installing ecommerce bundle in pimcore

Tags: pimcore

poping this errror -> No 'php' executable found, please install the application or add it to the PATH (in system settings or to your PATH environment variable Trace:

[image]

Comment: Do you really use Windows? Have you tried to add php.exe to PATH?